# How to import Javascript file into Ionic/Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

For my Ionic 2 app, I'm using the three.js and a PLYLoader extension for three.js (found here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/PLYLoader.js)

I'm able to import in three.js just fine, by putting this in my `index.html`:

```
<script src="three.js"> </script>
```

Then in the relevant TypeScript file:

```
import * as THREE from '../../three.js';
```

So I'm trying to do the same thing with PLYLoader:

```
<script src="PLYLoader.js"> </script>
```

and

```
import * as PLYLoader from '../../PLYLoader.js';
```

But whenever I load the page, I get the following error:

```
ionViewDidLoad error: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__three_js__.PLYLoader is not a constructor
```

Ionic/Angular is obviously able to find the file, but for some reason the TypeScript isn't interpreting the JavaScript class correctly. Is there a reasonable solution to this?

Comment: Hi Mike, i am having the same problem. Did you fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any exports in PLYLoader. That could be one issue.

Answer (score 0):

On the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-ply-loader), it specifically has this code:

```
const THREE = require("three");
const PLYLoader = require("three-ply-loader");
PLYLoader(THREE);
```